# form内にsubmitしないbuttonを配置したい

Tags: html

`form`タグ内に`button`タグを配置したところ、クリックするとsubmitされてしまう様なのですが
これをsubmitしないただのボタンとして扱いたい場合はどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

typeに"button"を指定してみてはどうでしょうか？
[button要素で送信・リセット・汎用ボタンを自由に作ろう](http://honttoni.blog74.fc2.com/blog-entry-153.html)

一部引用

> type="部品の種類" submit（送信ボタン）、reset（リセットボタン）、button（汎用ボタン）の3つ。
>   デフォルトは「submit」なので、typeを指定しなければ送信ボタンになります。
>   ＊ただ、IE7以下ではデフォルトが「button」になります。
>   IE7以下でを送信ボタンとして使う場合は、キチンとtype="submit"と書く必要があります。

```
<button type="submit">送信する</button>
<button type="reset">リセット</button>
<button type="button">トップページへ</button>
```